# Show that an open interval $(a,b)$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

My attempt:

Let $(a,b)$ be the open interval. We probably need to show that $(a,b)$ is an open ball so something in this form $B(x,r)$.

So I chose $x=(a+b)/2$. Now let $y \in (a,b)$. Then, $(a-b)/2<(a+b)/2-y<(b-a)/2$.

Let $r = min[0,|\frac{a+b}{2}-b|,|\frac{a+b}{2}-a|]$.So $y \in  B(x,r)$.

This has been my attempt,I know it doesn't make any sense but I tried this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply say that$$(a,b)=B\left(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{b-a}2\right),$$since\begin{align}x\in B\left(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{b-a}2\right)&\iff\left|x-\frac{a+b}2\right|<\frac{b-a}2\\&\iff\frac{a-b}2<x-\frac{a+b}2<\frac{b-a}2\\&\iff a<x<b.\end{align}Concerning your approach, note that $\min\left\{0,\left|\frac{a+b}2-b\right|,\left|\frac{a+b}2-a\right|\right\}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're mixing together two things: one is showing $(a,b)$ is an open ball, and the other is showing $(a,b)$ is an open set (i.e., it is union of open balls; what you're doing with the $y$).

To show $(a,b)$ is an open ball, you start correctly by finding the midpoint, $x = (a+b)/2$. Now what's the radius of the ball? Well, from the midpoint to the two boundary points $a$ and $b$, the distance is: $|b-x| = |x-a| = |(b-a)/2|$. So the radius of the set is $r=(b-a)/2$. So $(a,b)= B( (a+b)/2, (b-a)/2 )$.